# How to pass string for EEPROM write for ATMega32? (in the following code)

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, c, microprocessor

How could I pass a string for EEPROM write first and read in the code as:

```
int main() 
{ 
    char display[30];    
    EEPROM_writedata(display); 
    LCD_senddata(0,EEPROM_print(1));//this wont work 
    LCD_senddata(0,display); //this works fine 
    return 1; 
} 

void EEPROM_writedata(char* name) 
{ 
    eeprom_update_block((const void *)name,(void*)1,20);    
}

char* EEPROM_print(int i) 
{ 
    char* send; 
    eeprom_read_block((void*)send,(const void*)1,10); 
    return send; 
} 

LCD_sendata(int, char*) 
{ 
    //codes for LCD initialize upto print 
}
```

I may have a lot of mistakes here because of less knowledge. Please specify if you get them. My problem is mainly pass string to EEPROM_write() and pass it to main from EEPROM_print(). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you *actually* get out of the eeprom printing?

Comment: I need to write a string to EEPROM and read it back to print it on LCD. Actually I need to manage a small database inside EEPROM.

Comment: Microcontrollers are very unforgiving for new C programmers. I suggest that you mock up the AVR libraries on a PC and test your code there. It may also be useful to brush up on your C, http://c.learncodethehardway.org/

Comment: I am using AVRStudio5 for avr simulating.and ya, really! I should brush up my c.

Comment: @Bishal What exactly does the EEPROM_print() return for you to display on the LCD?  Not what do you *want* it to return, but what *does* it return?  What is "not working" about it?  Is it just blank? Is it gibberish?  What?

Comment: @Majenko It should return bytes read from EEPROM.

Comment: @JobyTaffey Thank you very much for the link you supplied on some other topic:
http://mainframe.cx/~ckuethe/avr-c-tutorial/lesson11.c
I got a lot of help from this.

Comment: @bishal yes, I know what it *should* return. But what are you experiencing it returning?

Answer (score 1):

Variables stored in the EEPROM on AVRs in C must be placed in the `.eeprom` section.

(From [http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group_*avr*_eeprom.html](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__eeprom.html))

```
#define     EEMEM   __attribute__((section(".eeprom")))
void        eeprom_write_block (const void *__src, void *__dst, size_t __n)
```

To store a variable in EEPROM and access it, you want something like:

```
char EEMEM myVar;

void writeMyVal(char c)
{
  eeprom_write_block(&c, &myVar, sizeof(myVar));
}

void readMyVal(char *c)
{
  eeprom_read_block((void*)c, &myVar, sizeof(myVar));
}
```

[Here's](http://blog.deathpod3000.com/?p=61) a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Thankx to all of you for your great help Actually I got my solution from:
http://mainframe.cx/~ckuethe/avr-c-tutorial/lesson11.c 
I edited the code as

```
 int main()
 {
 char display[30],write[]="write something inside EEPROM";
 EEPROM_writedata(&write); //initially, EEPROM_writedata(write);
 LCD_senddata(0,EEPROM_print(1));
 LCD_senddata(0,&display); //initially, LCD_senddata(0,display);
 return 1;
 }
```

Comment: You still have a bug that will come back and bite you in the future even if it seems to work now.  In your EEPROM_print() routine you need to initialize the send pointer to the address of a buffer which has been allocated in a way that while survive the completing of the function.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @ChrisStratton, you need to allocate space for `char *send` that is not local to the method.  Read the question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope